# Is it possible to update multiple records in a table with different values?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, case

I am working with SQL and I need to do several Updates with the following:

```
UPDATE databaseID SET count = 51 WHERE codCountry = "ES" AND file = "ES_IN.txt"
UPDATE databaseID SET count = 15 WHERE codCountry = "ES" AND file = "ES_DA.txt"
UPDATE databaseID SET count = 84 WHERE codCountry = "CO" AND file = "CO_SE.txt"
UPDATE databaseID SET count = 74 WHERE codCountry = "CO" AND file = "CO_TE.txt"
```

My question is, is it possible to do something like the following, that is, update multiple rows of the table in a single query?

```
UPDATE databaseID (SET count = 51 WHERE codCountry = "ES" AND file = "ES_IN.txt"), (SET count = 15 WHERE codCountry = "ES" AND file = "ES_DA.txt")...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
UPDATE databaseID 
SET count = CASE 
    WHEN codCountry = 'ES' AND file = 'ES_IN.txt' THEN 51 
    WHEN codCountry = 'ES' AND file = 'ES_DA.txt' THEN 15
    WHEN codCountry = 'CO' AND file = 'CO_SE.txt' THEN 84
    WHEN codCountry = 'CO' AND file = 'CO_TE.txt' THEN 74
    ELSE count
END
```

MySql will not actually update the row if the `ELSE` part is reached.

Or you can add a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE databaseID 
SET count = CASE 
    WHEN codCountry = 'ES' AND file = 'ES_IN.txt' THEN 51 
    WHEN codCountry = 'ES' AND file = 'ES_DA.txt' THEN 15
    WHEN codCountry = 'CO' AND file = 'CO_SE.txt' THEN 84
    WHEN codCountry = 'CO' AND file = 'CO_TE.txt' THEN 74
END
WHERE (codCountry, file) IN 
  ('ES', 'ES_IN.txt'), ('ES', 'ES_DA.txt'), ('CO', 'CO_SE.txt'), ('CO', 'CO_TE.txt')
```

and remove the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` expression.

Comment: How can I add the WHERE clause?

Comment: @print as it is at the end of the statement.

Comment: Yes, but I can't get it into the Update

Comment: I would think that by adding the WHERE clause the WHENs could be heard, I don't understand then what is the use of adding the WHERE clause now?

Comment: @print the use of the WHERE clause is to filter the table so that fewer rows are processed. If you don't use it then the UPDATE statement will try to update all the rows of the table according to the conditions in the CASE expression. If none of the conditions is satisfied then no update will be done. In the extreme case that all the rows of the table fall under one of the 4 conditions then the WHERE clause is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a derived table and `join`:

```
UPDATE databaseID d JOIN
       (SELECT 'ES' as codCountry, 'ES_IN.txt' as file, 15 as count UNION ALL
        SELECT 'CO' as codCountry, 'CO_SE.txt' as file, 51 as count UNION ALL
         . . .
       ) x
       USING (codCountry, file)        
    SET d.count = x.count;
```

This is even simpler if the original data is already in a table.  Then you can just use that table.

Comment: with mysql 8.0.19+ or mariadb 10.3.3+ you can use the VALUES table constructor (though the syntax and usage unfortunately varies between the two)